# Kivy log viewer on windows

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I'm building apps with kivy and kivymd, and i want to see the log that happens in my kivy app when i run it on my Android phone,i know about linux method ,but is there any method to view log on windows?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Solved,i used a mobile app testing website which provides logcat [Like this website](https://www.browserstack.com/android-testing)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).